# Get part of a string in a sql statement based on a character

Tags: mysql, database

I have a sql statement as below

```
SELECT cc.id, SUBSTRING(cc.path,2) AS pointer
FROM table AS CC
```

the field path is like

```
/2/3 or /3/23/4
```

What I'm trying to get is the number AFTER the second slash.  I can't use SUBSTRING(cc.path,2,1) because it isn't always a single digit number.  How can I get that number based on getting a number at the end OR between 2 slashes?

Thanks

Kieran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cc.path,'/',3),'/',-1)
```

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Comment: This actually gives the correct solution, [working sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a493d)

Comment: Thanks.  Thats what I am after.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the length (3rd parameter) by computing the starting position of next '/' in your string. you can get something like this..

```
substring(originalstring,(string,stringpos(string,'/'))
```

Additionaly check this article[sql substring()](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/tip-of-the-day.aspx?tkey=4AB06421-E859-4B5F-A948-0C9640F3108D&tkw=uses-of-the-substring-string-function). Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For your second condition please try :

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cc.path, '/', -2),'/',1)
```

Adjust arguments as per requirements.